# C# .NET SQL building classes from code stored in database and executing during runtime

Tags: c#, sql, compilation, runtime

Is it possible to load base class and a child classes from database during runtime of an application and compile them and execute the code? With inheritance? If so how does one do it.

I've created a created a basic ERD of the database of my needs and attached to the post.

A basic structure of the database table will be as follows:

The table structure will look like:

```
CREATE TABLE Class
(
    ClassID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    BaseClassID INT NULL,
    ClassName VARCHAR(MAX),
    Code VARCHAR(MAX),
    FOREIGN KEY (BaseClassID) REFERENCES Class(ClassID)
)

CREATE TABLE Item
(
   ItemID int primary key NOT NULL,
   ClassID int NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (ClassID) REFERENCES Class(ClassID)
)
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We don't like links, links can die. Can you please bring the image into the question.

Comment: Sorry about the image, Stackoverflow doesn't allow the upload of images when you do not have atleast 10 credits.

Comment: Compiling code during runtime is possible. Check the class Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider and its method CompileAssemblyFromSource. I wrote such code a few weeks back. It's truly amazing :) You'll need to build the source code of your classes as a string during runtime. If no one will provide a correct solution I will write one a little later.

Comment: @NoelWidmer Thank you for your reply, this solution seems to be what i was looking for. I am in the process of trying it out.